# Create sql query string

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have a problem to create query for table

mouventDeStock

```
|| idMv || dateMv ||qteMv || typeMV(bit) || codeMv ||
```

the feild type is either 0 or 1  if 0 means out of the stock , if 1 means means input of stock

i wanna calculate the qte witch is equal to

```
qte = ( sum(qteMv) where typeMv = 1 )  - ( sum(qteMv) where typeMv = 0 )
```

how i can't do it in sql

```
(select sum(mvQte) from mouvementDeStock 
 where (mvType = 1 and mvCode = 'ART_18'))
 -
 (select sum(mvQte) from mouvementDeStock 
 where (mvType = 0 and mvCode = 'ART_18')
```

but it's not working at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
Select Y.S - X.S As Sum from
(select sum(qteMv) S from mouventDeStock where typemv=1 and codemv = 'ART_18') Y,
(select sum(qteMv) S from mouventDeStock where typemv=0 and codemv = 'ART_18') X;
```

Comment: yes it works but i try to assign the query isn't works              i want to do this       table.feild = result of query ;

Comment: Are you updating a existing record or inserting into a new table? Post the table definition too.

Comment: i want to update a only one record , my table is about sales products and buying products and i have separte them with type of mouvment   mvType, and i want to calculate total(QtySalesProducts) - total(QtyBuyingProducts) and Update qty in table products , i hope is clear now

Comment: how i can set sum in case of NUll as zero , because X-NULL = NULL and this is a problem

Comment: Use `IFNULL`. `Select IFNULL(Y.S, 0) - IFNULL(X.S, 0) ...` See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries to calculate the subtotals, but your *entire* statement must be a valid SQL statement, so you need to wrap another `SELECT` around them:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(mvQte) FROM mouvementDeStock 
        WHERE mvType = 1 AND mvCode = 'ART_18')
       -
       (SELECT SUM(mvQte) FROM mouvementDeStock
        WHERE mvType = 0 AND mvCode = 'ART_18')
```

---

If you want to be clever, you can do this with a single sum, by making all out-of-stock `mvQte` values negative by multiplying them with -1:

```
SELECT SUM(mvQte * CASE mvType WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)
FROM mouvementDeStock
WHERE mvCode = 'ART_18'
```

([CASE expression documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case))